# Why in android in calling activity is not stopped?

Tags: android, android-activity, kotlin

When any activity is running and if we change the orientation mean (portrait to  landscape or landscape to portrait ),then activity face is onPause , OnStop,onDestroy then again it goes to on onRestart , onStart..
Then my question is that if anyone is calling  me and my mobile is in ringing mode then i change the orientation then why the ring isn't break or isn't cut the call ???

Comment: did your device changed orientation while the call was coming ?

Comment: @Sahil yes , it changes orientation..

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can have a static variable of the Media Player and make its base class as Singleton class. Suppose our Activity orientation changes now, Everything will be recreated on orientation change but Mp variable will not be recreated because of static property.

Also, go through [onConfigurationChanged](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onConfigurationChanged%28android.content.res.Configuration%29), which will help you to achieve the same.

Then there are services too depending upon your code architecture.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

calling is one kind of service and it may be working in background .... so that could be one reason why call is not cut or break ..

Comment: may be possible  bro.. but i didn't think that is